# Regex to compare and extract alphabet characters using python

Tags: python, regex, dataframe

Hi I have a dataset as shown below:

```
Format,Message,time
A,ab@1 yl@5 rd@20 pp@40,3
B,bc@1 gn@7 yl@20 ss@25 rd@50, 21
C,cc@1 yl@9 rd@20, 22
```

I would like to use extracted numbers from yl and rd of Messages then do a comparison of numbers between its number (e.g. yl@5 ---> 5) and the time column's number. so if row 1, 3 will be compared with 5 and 20. So if it is lesser than both element, it will be assign with a value g. If the time is 7, value y will be assigned and likewise if it is 20 and above, it will be asigned as r.

So it will be like

```
Format,Message,time,status
A,ab@1 yl@5 rd@20 pp@40,3,g
B,bc@1 gn@7 yl@20 ss@25 rd@50,21,y
C,cc@1 yl@9 rd@20,22,r
```

Comment: Please do post what you've tried.

Comment: `re.search('yl@(\d+).+?rd@(\d+)', 'ab@1 yl@5 rd@20 pp@40').groups()` is the Regex that will get you tuple of those numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is really a number of questions. From the 'dataframe' tag, it appears you're doing this using pandas. The regular expression you're asking about could extra the numbers for 'yl' and 'rd' (if any, I'm assuming they are always there). But a regular expression typically doesn't do math or numerical comparisons, so that's a third bit.

A regular expression to match the numerical value for 'yl' (assuming integer, not float):

```
r'yl@(\d+)'
```

You could extract them in a single expression, but that would assume they are always in the same order, or become a complicated regular expression.

To ensure only `yl@5` gets matched, but something like `xyl@5` does not, you can add some restrictions to the start (require space or start of line) and end (require space or end of line):

```
r'(^|\s)yl@(\d+)($|\s)'
```

Or, if you have situations where `yl` is name-spaced, like `a:yl`, you can add that as well:

```
r'(^|\s)([a-z]+:)?l@(\d+)($|\s)'
```

However, all this is just building more specific expressions using the regular expression language. A very good tool for writing regex I enjoy using (no affiliation) is RegexBuddy, but there are pretty good online tools as well, like https://regex101.com/.

Used in a code example basically doing what you suggested:

```
import re
from pandas import DataFrame

df = DataFrame({
    'Format': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'Message': ['ab@1 yl@5 rd@20 pp@40', 'bc@1 gn@7 yl@20 ss@25 rd@50', 'cc@1 yl@9 rd@20'],
    'time': [3, 21, 22]
})


def determine_status(row):
    def find(tag, message):
        match = re.search(rf"{tag}@(\d+)", message)
        if match:
            return match.group(1)
        else:
            raise ValueError(f'{tag} not in message.')

    yl = int(find('yl', row['Message']))
    rd = int(find('rd', row['Message']))

    time = int(row['time'])
    if time < yl < rd:
        return 'g'
    if yl <= time < rd:
        return 'y'
    return 'r'


df['status'] = df.apply(determine_status, axis=1)

print(df)
```

The `find` function takes a tag and a message and produces the numerical value for the tag in the message using a regular expression.

The `determine_status` function does just that - it expects a row from a DataFrame and will use the `Message` and `time` column to determine a status and returns it.

`df.apply` is then used to create a new `status` column and fill it with the result of `determine_status` for every row in the DataFrame.

You didn't specify what version of Python you are using, but if it's a version before Python 3.6, you'll find that the expressions like `f'{tag} not in message.'` won't work - instead you'd use something like `'{tag} not in message.'.format(tag=tag)`.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your ans, would like to ask the same question that I've asked on the other ans, Will the code apply if the element is in such format(e.g. a:yl@5 )?

Comment: Yes, in fact, the code would even work if there were fragments like xyl@5, since it still ends in 'yl' followed by an @ and some numbers, which is what the regex `yl@(\d+)` matches.

You could require that it be surrounded by white-space with something like `(^|\s)yl@(\d+)($|\s)` matching group 2 instead of 1.

Or, if you want to add an optional namespacing, something like `(^|\s)([a-z]+:)?yl@(\d+)($|\s)` would work, if you match the 3rd group.

Comment: Some how I've receive error as such "ValueError: ('yl not in message.', 'occurred at index 0')"

Comment: That is actually expected: apparently, not all messages in your data have an `yl` element? What do you expect to get if there is no `yl` in the message? The error is generated by the line `raise ValueError` in the script, to indicate this problem.

Comment: Apart from the header row and 1st row of data, the rest of rows should have element yl

Comment: In the example you provided, all rows of data have 'yl', so if you're running the code on a dataset where the first line doesn't, you can either skip or remove that line, or change the code throwing the exception - however, the error is thrown because a line of data in your dataset apparently does not have an 'yl'.

Comment: I tried removing the first row and process the data which gave me the error as shown above. does the header row affect?

Comment: Would like to check why is the status only returning value 'r' instead of meeting the condition

Comment: Depending on how you load the data into a DataFrame, the header row may or may not have an effect - this goes beyond the scope of your question. 'r' is set as status for all cases where yl does not meet the previous conditions, see the last line of `determine_status`. You'll have to add to your example in the question, if you need further answers. Please clarify there, or accept the working answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this can be done with built in string functions. Try this!

```
def f(mess):
    p1 = mess.find('yl')
    p2 = mess.find('rd')
    return int(mess[p1+3:].split(' ')[0]),int(mess[p2+3:].split(' ')[0])

df['vals'] =df['Message'].apply(f) 

df['status'] = df.apply(lambda row:  'g' if min(row['vals']) > row.time \
                        else 'y' if row.vals[1]>row.time  \
                        else 'r', axis=1)

print(df)
```

output:

```
  Format                  Message  time      vals status
0      A    ab@1 yl@5 rd@20 pp@40     3   (5, 20)      g
1      B  bc@1  yl@20 ss@25 rd@50    21  (20, 50)      y
2      C          cc@1 yl@9 rd@20    22   (9, 20)      r
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the ans! Would like to check with you on the code. What does it means having the "+3" for the return part?

Comment: p1 picks the location of start of yl, then we have to move 3 place to get to the numbers until we see a space

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Will the code apply if the element is in such format(e.g. a:yl@5 )?

Comment: yes, it will. It simply search for the location of y1 in the whole string. Hope it helps

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply, I'm still on the midst of trying! Will accept it after the problem is solved! Thanks once again!

Comment: Hi again! I encounter an error "name 'apply' is not defined. Is this something to do with version issue?

Comment: I had assumed df is your dataframe. Make sure, you use the same convention

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185238/discussion-between-ailearning-and-thanksforhelping).

Comment: My status column only reflect r

Comment: can you add the example where it failed!