# Extracting number from irregular value with python

Tags: python, regex

I have data as shown below:

```
Format,Message,time
A,gn@2 ab@1 yl@5 rd@20 pp@40,3
B,w:w23w4w5w6w7gn@3 gn@7 yl@20 ss@25 rd@50,21
C,cc@1 fgn@4 yl@9 rd@20,22
D,rg@1 fedsf@5 rww@10 yl@20 rd@26,30
```

My expected outcome is to extract numbers that come after gn,yl and rd

```
Format,Message,time,gn,yl,rd
A,gn@2 ab@1 yl@5 rd@20 pp@40,3,2,5,20
B,w:w23w4w5w6w7gn@3 an@7 yl@20 ss@25 rd@50,21,3,20,50
C,cc@1 fgn@4 yl@9 rd@20,22,4,9,20
D,rg@1 fedsf@5 rww@10 yl@20 rd@26,30,0,20,26
```

as of now im able to get yl and rd but im unable to extract numbers that comes after gn. Do note that gn element might consist of some other characters before gn and the numbers are required after gn@

```
def f(mess):
    p1 = mess.find('yl')
    p2 = mess.find('rd')
    b = mess[p1+3:].split(' ')[0]
    c = mess[p2+3:].split(' ')[0]
    return int(b),int(c)
id['vals'] = id['Message'].apply(f) #with this im able to get the numbers from yl and rd
```

Comment: I like your username

Comment: What is wrong with using the same logic for gn, with a p3 variable ?

Comment: looks pretty similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53773067/1358308

Comment: i tried using p3, but due to the difference in length for gn element, it did not extract the numbers and end up extracting some other characters within that value. I will update my question as the value in my actual data is much longer. I shorten and changed the data to try and consult so that I can understand the logic

Comment: @SamMason it is a step further than the question asked in the link to extract more element

Comment: Grismar's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53773294/1358308) seems to basically do what you want

Comment: It managed to solve the yl and rd, but it is not able to extract gn @SamMason

Comment: Why not just run a find/replace like `result = re.sub(r"(gn@)(\d+)(.*?yl@)(\d+)(.*?rd@)(\d+)(.*)", r"\1\2\3\4\5\6\7,\2,\4,\6", subject)`?

Answer (score 1):

Let's move stepwise to tackle this problem.

1. Get only the lines that are of interest to you.
2. Remove the data that might not be of use to us.
3. Use the data that is left to extract the information.

Let's assume that I have the input stored in a variable `data` and I need the output stored in a list of tuples called `final`. Here's how I'll tackle this problem.

```
useful = data.split('\n')[1:]  ## Step 1
code = [x[1].strip() for x in useful.split(',')] ## Step 2
gn_value = -1
yl_value = -1
rd_value = -1
for line in code:
    for each in line.split(' '): ## Step 3
        if 'gn@' in each:
            gn_value = int(each[each.find('gn@')+3:])
        elif 'yl@' in each:
            yl_value = int(each[each.find('yl@')+3:])
        elif 'rd@' in each:
            rd_value = int(each[each.find('rd@')+3:])
    final.append(gn_value, yl_value, rd_value)
```

Note: The above solution has been developed with the assumption that there are not multiple occurrences of any of the values in any given line.

Let me know if you might have any queries.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following expression:

```
mess = 'gn@2 ab@1 yl@5 rd@20 pp@40'
result = [ int(m.split('@')[1])  for m in mess.split() if m.split('@')[0] in ['gn', 'yl', 'rd'] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex.

**Demo:**

```
import re
s = """A,gn@2 ab@1 yl@5 rd@20 pp@40,3,2,5,20
B,w:w23w4w5w6w7gn@3 an@7 yl@20 ss@25 rd@50,21,3,20,50
C,cc@1 fgn@4 yl@9 rd@20,22,4,9,20
C,cc@1 yl@9 rd@20,22,4,9,20"""

for line in s.splitlines():
    gn = re.search(r"gn@(.?\S)", line)
    if gn:
        gn = gn.group(1)

    yl = re.search(r"yl@(.?\S)", line)
    if yl:
        yl = yl.group(1)

    rd = re.search(r"rd@(.?\S)", line)
    if rd:
        rd = rd.group(1)
    print(gn, yl, rd)
```

**Output:**

```
2 5 20
3 20 50
4 9 20
None 9 20
```

Comment: Quick question! Will this work if lets say that I have a total of 1000 rows of data and maybe 20% of this rows do not have this gn element, Coz i tried using your method, it actually shows an error of 'nonetype' object has no attribute 'group' so i realised that actually there were some lines with gn element

Comment: You need to add a check condition to handle that. Updated Snippet

Comment: Will you be able to guide me towards this step?

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'll add my variant too

```
mess = """
A,gn@2 ab@1 yl@5 rd@20 pp@40,3
B,w:w23w4w5w6w7gn@3 gn@7 yl@20 ss@25 rd@50, 21
C,cc@1 fgn@4 yl@9 rd@20, 22
"""

for row in mess.strip().splitlines():
    print("ROW:", row)
    for col in row.split(" "):
        try:
            k, v = col.split('@')
            print("%s=%d" % (k[-2:], int(v.split(',', 1)[0])))
        except:
            print("leftover=%s" % col)
    print()
```

And this produces:

```
ROW: A,gn@2 ab@1 yl@5 rd@20 pp@40,3
gn=2
ab=1
yl=5
rd=20
pp=40

ROW: B,w:w23w4w5w6w7gn@3 gn@7 yl@20 ss@25 rd@50, 21
gn=3
gn=7
yl=20
ss=25
rd=50
leftover=21

ROW: C,cc@1 fgn@4 yl@9 rd@20, 22
cc=1
gn=4
yl=9
rd=20
leftover=22
```

I'd be quite easy to push them into dict of lists, no matter if you have multiple repeating keys or values :)
No need for multiple conditionals and cherry-picking. All key=value pairs are accessible.